# raffle arraylist validation

Tags: c#, random, arraylist

I'm making a raffle c# program where random of 1-10 numbers will be drawn and put it on `ArrayList` and if the number is already drawn then it should not be place in the array...my problem is even if I validate it, it still added on the array.

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("RAFFLES");
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
Random rnd = new Random();

ret: Console.Write("Press 1 to draw");
int draw = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

switch(draw)
{
     case 0: break;
     case 1:

         if (array.Contains(rnd.Next(1, 11)))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Already Exist");                        
         }
         else
             array.Add(rnd.Next(1, 11));

         goto ret;

     case 2: 

         foreach (var a in array)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
          break;
}
```

Comment: Normally you'd shuffle and take as many as you need (also avoid infinite loop at the end that you should have with "check if taken" if you did code properly). Otherwise please step through the code and come up with [MCVE].

Comment: Your goto makes me want to vomit. = )

Comment: Not sure if it quite reaches the level of vomit but it does leave my with an unsettled stomach that could get worse.

Answer (score 3):

You should store the first `rnd.Next(1, 11)` in a variable:

```
int x = rnd.Next(1, 11);
if (array.Contains(x))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Already Exist");
}
else
     array.Add(x);
```

Comment: I belive (based on how this assignment is usually setup) OP also need `while` to generate random number - otherwise it will not draw anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing the result of

```
rnd.Next(1, 11)
```

So when it hits your else statement it runs rnd.next() again to get a new number bypassing your check.

It should be:

```
case 1:
    int rndNumber = rnd.Next(1,11);
    if (array.Contains(rndNumber))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Already Exist");
    }
    else
        array.Add(rndNumber);
```